# Reading .dbf files using .NET Compact Framework on Windows Mobile Devices

Tags: .net, compact-framework, dbf, sdf, compact-database

I want to read `.dbf` file on `Windows Mobile 5.0` device (`Windows CE` based devices in general).

Basically, I need to convert `.dbf` file to `.sdf` file & then use `.sdf` in my application.
The only reason for this conversion requirement is the size of the `.dbf` file.
I don't need all the fields of `.dbf` file but only a few specific fields of the records.

I can use `C#` or`VB.NET` or any native language if that is required.

Any help is much appreciated.

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 2):

Guineu is a runtime library that executes FoxPro code on Windows Mobile including accessing DBF files. In addition you can use it on the desktop to read from DBF files and write to SDF files. The Guineu runtime library is accessible from .NET, as well, if you don't want to use FoxPro.

Answer (score 1):

If your DBF file is in FoxPro/dBase/Clipper format (it probably is), then [CodeBase](http://www.codebase.com/products/windows_ce/) will work for you.